# Is there a way to add a function to all html element with a specific class

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to select all html elements with a specific class and call a function with onClick event

**HTML Code**

```html
<div class="card shadow boxToggle"></div>
<div class="card shadow boxToggle"></div>
<div class="card shadow boxToggle"></div>
<div class="card shadow boxToggle"></div>
```

When I click on any `div.boxToggle`, I want to add a class to it.

### What I Tried

**1. Approach**

```html
<div class="card shadow boxToggle" onClick="a_function()"></div>
<div class="card shadow boxToggle" onClick="a_function()"></div>
```

**2. Approach**

```js
const box = document.querySelectorAll('.boxToggle')
box.forEach((b) => {
  b.addEventListener("click", toggle)
})

function toggle(event) {
  console.log(event)
  event.target.classList.toggle("boxChange");
}
```

Is there any other shorter and better approach for solving this problem without using jQuery?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, delegation

```js
const toggle = event => {
  const tgt = event.target.closest("div");
  if (tgt.classList.contains("card")) {
    console.log(tgt.textContent)
    tgt.classList.toggle("boxChange")
  }
};

document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", toggle);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="card shadow boxToggle"><h1>1</h1><p>Click me too</p></div>
  <div class="card shadow boxToggle">2</div>
  <div class="card shadow boxToggle">3</div>
  <div class="card shadow boxToggle">4</div>
</div>
```

To remove (but I recommend setting a flag in a data attribute or just a boolean)

```
 document.getElementById("container").removeEventListener("click", toggle)
```

Comment: I am running into a problem here, try adding any tag inside boxToggle, then click on that element, the class will be added to that element as well.
<div class="card shadow boxToggle"><h1>Class will be added to me as well, if you click on me</h1></div>

Comment: That is fixable give me a minute

Comment: You mentioned adding more event listeners is bad. But isn't it just the same if not worse to add an event listener to the whole container?

Comment: Not at all. And it is important to add it as close to the elements as possible

Comment: Oh..just see your answer. I post a similar answer as you. I also add a line to early return in case the user clicks the container div. see my answer.

Comment: One quick question. How can we use removeEventListener here?

Comment: Why would you want to? If you do not want the event handler to do anything, set a data-attribute or similar. removeEventListener is always a code smell to me

Comment: @ChiragArora If you do want to use `removeEventListener`, you just need a named function as your listener. (The `toggle` function qualifies.) You remove the listener by specifying the same event and the same named function, like `myElementWithListener.removeEventListener("click", toggle);`

Comment: Adding an if condition was a nice approach. Thanks!

Comment: I added how to remove although as I said, I do not recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Your second approach is good. Event listeners are generally preferred over inline event handlers.

You might consider using `.selectElementsByClassName` instead of `.querySelectorAll` since the former will keep a "live" list of associated elements on the page. Perhaps even better, you could take advantage of [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation), as demonstrated in this snippet:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", toggle);

function toggle(event){
  if(event.target.classList.contains("boxToggle")){
    event.target.classList.toggle("boxChange");
  }    
}
```

```css
.card{ height: 2em; width: 5em; margin: 2px 0; border: 1px solid grey; }
.boxChange{ background-color: skyblue; }
```

```html
<div class="card shadow boxToggle"></div>
<div class="card shadow boxToggle"></div>
```

Comment: I do not recommend using document to delegate from. See my answer for a tighter rein on the event handling

Answer (score -1):

This could solve your problem:

```
 var boxToggle = document.getElementsByClassName("boxToggle");
 for (var i = 0; i < boxToggle.length; i++) {
     boxToggle[i].className+=' card';
 }
```